# gnuplot - USING string variables

Tags: string, gnuplot

I'm trying something very simple ...

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset

filename = "something_or_other"

set terminal pngcairo dashed size 800,400 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output filename.".png"
set title filename."\n"
set xlabel "probably time"
set ylabel "probably something else" offset graph 0.2,0.6 rotate by 0

plot filename.".dat" using 1:2 lc rgb "#00E80000" title "measurements"

!display filename.".png"
```

except `filename` stays just like that and doesn't get interpreted as a string.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exlamation mark `!` at the beginning of the line makes gnuplot send this whole line as it is to a shell. So, here you cannot use any gnuplot variables and string concatenation. For this you can use `system()`:

```
system(sprintf("display %s.png", filename))
```

Comment: I hadn't realised it was only the last line that wasn't working. Thanks a lot.